# Сохранение красивой истории коммитов. Зачем?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

Зачем , например, пользоваться cherry-pick, если можно сделать мердж отдельных коммитов из другой ветки? Это ведь делают для сабжа, зачем ?

Comment: Давайте гиперболизируем вопрос для наглядности: зачем вообще история коммитов?

Comment: @Etki, для лулзов? :)

Comment: @TheDoctor ну да. Хе. Как я не догадался-то. Хе. Хе.

Answer (score 5):

Если вопрос звучит как "зачем пользоваться `cherry-pick`, когда есть `merge`?", то ответ: незачем. Обычно ветки создают для изоляции работы над какой-нибудь фичей, и нет особого смысла "сплющивать" историю коммитов по окончании работы. Это скорее даже вредно, так как мешает отслеживать динамику разработки.

Если же вопрос звучит как "какие практические применения есть у `cherry-pick`?", то вот вам пару вариантов. Во-первых, можно случайно сделать коммит не в ту ветку, тогда `cherry-pick` поможет быстро и красиво исправить ситуацию. Во-вторых, предположим такую ситуацию: разработка ведётся одновременно в двух ветках, которые по каким-либо причинам пока нельзя смерджить, и нужно одновременно пофиксать баг в обеих. В этой ситуации `cherry-pick` снова выручает разработчика.

Бонусом можно упомянуть `rebase`. С одной стороны, перенос целой ветки - это переписывание истории, мешающее отслеживать динамику разработки. С другой - возможность без запутывания истории мерджами включить в ветку часть коммитов с новым (исправленным) функционалом, необходимым в разработке.

Git хорош тем, что позволяет решать одни и те же задачи различными путями, подстраивающимися под потребности и вкусы разработчика. Конкретная политика использования `merge`/`cherry-pick`/`rebase` может отличаться в разных проектах, поэтому чёткого ответа на ваш вопрос быть не может.

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко, то случается так, что нужно залезть в дебри истории репозитория, чтобы понять для чего была сделана та или иная правка. Чтобы можно было понять, что происходит вся история должна быть "красивой", т.е наглядной. Что это значит? Это значит, что описания коммитов должны быть подробными, а слияния очевидными(более подробно про это я написал [здесь](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/08/03/git_commits_description.aspx))

Что касается `cherry-pick` и `rebase` побочных веток перед слиянием - на мой взгляд это не лучший выбор, т.к. в угоду "красоте", теряется реальная история. Т.е подобным образом уменьшается возможность полноценного анализа причины и последовательности изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Одна из причин для "причёсывания" коммитов - соблюдение некоего общего уровня гранулярности. Это даёт возможность отследить историю разработки с одной высоты обзора.

Удобство это примерно того же сорта, что и удобство от одинаковой глубины вызовов в коде в рамках одного метода. Или удобство от одинаковой гранулярности классов в пакете. Кажется, в программировании это называется принципом минимальной информированности.

В целом, история коммитов должна линейно провести нас по истории развития проекта от начала до текущего коммита. Или вопрос в том, какие именно практические задачи с помощью этой истории можно решить?

UPD. Кстати говоря, с переписыванием истории коммитов связана одна концептуальная проблема. И проблема эта - с корректностью переписанных коммитов. Предположим, навели красоту и сребэйзили ветку фичи с десятком коммитов в основную. В итоге может так оказаться, что попытка сборки каких-то коммитов из этого десятка закончится неудачей, несмотря на то, что головной коммит проходит всю интеграцию. В этом случае выходит не такая уж и красивая история. Вот что с этим делать?

Comment: у ребейза такой же интерфейс, как и у мерджа: нашлась ошибка - остановка - фикс вручную - rebase --continue

Comment: Для того, чтобы нашлась ошибка, о которой я говорю, необходимо, скажем, прогнать сборку на сервере непрерывной интеграции. Разумеется, никто этого не делает для каждого коммита при ребэйзе. Остановка происходит только в случае конфликта изменений.

Comment: Мм, ну я вроде всего один раз с таким сталкивался, и CI-сервер все равно же это заблочит, когда это дело окажется в dev-ветке. С мерджем ровно то же самое может произойти.

Comment: CI сервер не будет собирать HEAD~5, оказавшийся в ветке в результате ребэйза. Он соберёт только HEAD. Вопрос, конечно, не вполне практический. Разработка идёт дальше вперёд. Но если когда-нибудь возникнет случайная необходимость вытащить коммит из прошлого - вполне можно об это споткнуться.

Comment: Да, но он же все равно известит о проблеме на уровне HEAD. Ну и на самом деле тут вопрос настройки сервера, выполняет он последний пришедший коммит или все, во втором случае можно будет без всякого bisect локализовать проблемное место.

Comment: На уровне HEAD эта проблема уже может быть решена. Например, я обновил в pom.xml версию библиотеки. А вторую библиотеку, связанную с первой, забыл. Вспомнил об этом через пару коммитов. Но поломанный коммит уже попал в историю. Да, гугление на скорую руку дало такой результат: Jenkins Pretested Integration Plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pretested+Integration+Plugin ). Тестируется каждый коммит.

Comment: Так если она уже решена, то в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что это грабли, на которые весьма легко наступить, и которые требуют особого внимания и специального обращения. Наличие подобного плагина для Дженкинса говорит скорее об актуальности проблемы, чем о том, что она решена. Сама по себе она не решается. Я привёл эту ситуацию в пример для того, чтобы указать на бОльшую серьёзность проблемы с красивой историей, чем это кажется на первый взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу целесообразности красивой истории коммитов в принципе: это дает ряд преимуществ:

1) порядок в репозитории - если над проектом работало несколько разработчиков это позволяет визуально оценить какой разраотчик какую задачу выполнял, и сколько времени это заняло, к примеру для последующего анализа адекватности оценки. Также это удобно если возникает необходимость откатиться на предыдущую версию, или если необходимо найти кусок функционала который был удален но нужно снова его найти, или найти место где возникла ошибка.

2) уменьшить количество конфликтов при слиянии

Далее по поводу `cherry-pick` - обычно он служит для того чтобы выдернуть одиночный коммит из одной ветки в другую. Для обеспечения красивой истории чаще используется `rebase`, ну или его разновидность в купе с pull: `git pull -r`

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты делаешь мердж - он делает слияние ветки (последнего коммита) с той веткой, с которой ты мерджишь.

В случае с cherry-pick коммиты из ветки применяются последовательно. Те - мердж текущей ветки с каждым коммитом из другой ветки последовательно.

Кроме того это не все возможности cherry-pic - ты можешь добавить в ветку только некоторую последовательность коммитов и тд.

Больше информации можно найти в документации.

Comment: Автор спрашивает не о функциональных озможностях, автор спрашивает о необходимости подобных телодвижений.

Comment: Так я об этом и говорю - что иногда нужно "собрать" ветку из разных коммитов, это удобно делать с помощью cherry-pick

Comment: ОК, вопрос автора тогда звучит так - "зачем иногда может потребоваться собрать ветку из разных коммитов?"